# Textfield Mandatory On basis of radio button selection- Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm having radio button with two value i.e, Individual and Firm.
I am looking for one scenario where if radio button having value Firm is selected, then `CompanyName` textinput should act as mandatory (required) field. And, when radio button having value Individual is selected, Then `CompanyName` textinput should act as Optional field.

I was not getting how to do it. I tried to add addAttribute in CompanyName textinput as mandatory. but it didn't worked as `RegisterForm.php` (model) is having few rules specified.

So, any idea how to do it. I'm not getting. Any help ?

**register.php** (view)

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'register-form']); ?>
    .
    .
    .
    <?= $form->field($model, 'AdminType')
            ->radioList(array('Individual'=>'An Individual', 'Firm'=>'Firm/Company/Group of Employees'))
            ->label('Are You')?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'CompanyName')->textInput()->label('Company Name') ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Register', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'name' => 'register-button' ]) ?>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

<script>
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).attr("value")=="Firm")
        {
            $('#registerform-companyname').addAttribute("required");
        }
    });
</script>
```

**RegisterForm.php** (model)

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use kartik\password\StrengthValidator;

class RegisterForm extends Model
{
    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $confirmPassword;
    public $AdminType;
    public $CompanyName;
    public $verifyCode;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
                [['fname','lname', 'email', 'password','confirmPassword','verifyCode','AdminType'], 'required'],
                ['email', 'email'],
            ['confirmPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'], 
                ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last I Got,

```
 ['company_name', 'required', 'when' => function($model){
    return ($model->user_type == 'Firm' ? true : false);
  }, 'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
      return $('input[type=\"radio\"][name=\"Users[user_type]\"]:checked').val() == 'Firm';
  }"],
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, having any kind of front end validation is BAD, as i can circumvent it by generating a post programmatically, and it will save the record without any problems, making a possibility of inconsistent records a reality.

What you want to do instead is create a custom validation rule function in your model, as well as add the rule to the validation array:

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;
use kartik\password\StrengthValidator;

class RegisterForm extends Model
{
    public $fname;
    public $lname;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $confirmPassword;
    public $AdminType;
    public $CompanyName;
    public $verifyCode;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
                [['fname','lname', 'email', 'password','confirmPassword','verifyCode','AdminType'], 'required'],
                ['email', 'email'],
                ['confirmPassword', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'], 
                ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],

                //add rule that uses the validator function
                ['AdminType','radioValidator'],
        ];
    }

    //implement the validator
    public function radioValidator($attribute, $params)
    {
        if($this->$attribute === 'Firm' && empty($this->$attribute))
            $this->addError('CompanyName', 'CompanyName cannot be blank');
    }
}
?>
```

<strike>Now your field generating code should look like this</strike>

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'CompanyName')->textInput()->label('Company Name')->error() ?>
```

Hope this helps you

Edit: As I am used to working with AR classes(which generally, when generated with gii, have validation automatically ), it did not cross my mind that you are using just a form model ( the one that was given as an example in the basic app)

forget the `->error()` in the field, also make sure you have the row

`if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {...}`

in your action

Comment: I asked my question here too @SmartCoder. Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969883/custom-validation-not-working-yii2-app-basic-yii2 on this.

Comment: Sorry to say @SmartCoder. Still not working. Feeling very sorry. But, not working. Whole day went for trying this. But, unfortunately still there where i was yesterday.